# C - Segmentation Fault when Calling an certain indexes from an array of function pointer

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

So I've ran into this problem before and I was wondering if anyone could help me with it. It's really strange and I've never seen anything like it.

So I have this setup function which basically fills my global array of operation functions:

```
//A function Pointer is a type def that accepts two ints
fcnptr *opCode_Array; //Global Array of fcnptrs
void SetUp() {
    int i;
    fcnptr temp[41] = {NULL,movOP_1,mviOP_2,mifOP_3,mitOP_4,lriOP_5,ldrOP_6,strOP_7,mvrOP_8,addOP_9,addriOP_10,subOP_11,mulOP_12, divOP_13, orOP_14, andOP_15, notOP_16, bOP_17, beqOP_18, bneOP_19, bgtOP_20, bgeOP_21, bltOP_22, bleOP_23, pushdOP_24, pushrOP_25, pushiOP_26, popdOP_27, poprOP_28, putiOP_29, putsOP_30, lineOP_31, getiOP_32, getsOP_33, callOP_34, retOP_35, stopOP_36,addOP_9,addriOP_10,subOP_11,mulOP_12};
    opCode_Array = (fcnptr*)malloc(41 * sizeof(fcnptr));
    //fill global array with functions
    for(i  = 0; i < 41; i++) {
        opCode_Array[i] = temp[i];

    }

}
```

Later on I have a function that calls the operation functions like so:

```
void fetchExecute(int codeStoreLength) {
    while(instructionPointer < codeStoreLength) {
        //ip does not point to the instruction it is to execute during the loop, but the instruction that follows it.
        instructionPointer += 3;
        (*opCode_Array[codeStore[instructionPointer - 3]])(codeStore[instructionPointer - 2], codeStore[instructionPointer - 1]);

    }
}
```

So normally this all works fine and dandy but last night and today I ran into some errors that caused segmentation faults when only calling specific functions, or more accurately, trying to access specific indexes of the opCode_Array.

If you noticed, I have two versions of the Addop, one at index 9 and another at index 37. When testing my function, I would get a segmentation fault when calling Addop at index 9 even when the code was completely commented out. I came up with a quick and dirty hack and just added another Addop to the end of the array and called addop from index 37 from now on. This worked completely fine and passed all the tests.

Now, another index is displaying the same behavior. It might be worth mentioning that this same index worked perfectly on previous tests. This has happened to a couple of my functions so I would rather just figure out why it's doing this than just move indexes around forever.

So far, I've tried p;laying around with pointers and making opCode_Array static but neither have helped..

Edit: Thank you everyone for the tips and help. I wasn't able to find the root of the problem but I was able to fix it by making the array local to fetchexecute instead of global. I would post more code but this is a school project that gets reused every year..

Lessons Learned? Don't make globals unless you have too I guess....

Comment: `opCode_Array = (fcnptr*)malloc(41 + sizeof(fcnptr));` should be `opCode_Array = (fcnptr*)malloc(41 * sizeof(fcnptr));`

Comment: `malloc(41 + sizeof(fcnptr))`: That's almost certainly meant to be a multiplication, not an addition.

Comment: Fixed, Thanks! Still getting the segfault though.

Comment: BTW: [don't cast malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger to see exactly where the segfault is happening and what the bogus pointer is?

Comment: You probably have a problem elsewhere in your code, and it's overwriting the contents of this array, which is causing the segfault.

Comment: You need to paste more code as the problem probably isn't here!

Comment: @Barmar is almost certainly correct. You're overwriting a function pointer with a junk value. Separate topic having nothing to do with the bug: There's no reason to copy a temp array of function pointers to the global. If you `#include` the function prototypes, there's no reason you can't just declare the global array and get rid of the setup function completely.